# maven datanucleus ASM issue

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, datanucleus

I got following error when build maven datanucleus based project. I have placed maven-datanucleus-plugin under plugin and correctly define the path which  contains persistent classes. Can anybody to help in this problem?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" You have selected to use ClassEnhancer "ASM" yet
the JAR for that enhancer does not seem to be in the CLASSPATH!
org.datanucleus.enhancer.NucleusEnhanceException: You have selected to use Class
Enhancer "ASM" yet the JAR for that enhancer does not seem to be in the CLASSPAT
H!
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.init(DataNucleusEnhancer
.java:212)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.addClasses(DataNucleusEn
hancer.java:370)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerProcessor$EnhanceRunnable.run(Enhanc
erProcessor.java:163)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use the enhancer and don't put *asm.jar* in the CLASSPATH, as per the docs. Can't be clearer.

Comment: There is no maven dependency for ASM ( i have exclude from datanucleus-enhancer also). But still i am getting same error.

Comment: The DN enhancer (which you are running) has a dependency on ASM as shown here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.0.1/datanucleus-enhancer-3.0.1.pom